# SelectLayerByLocation_management gives ERROR 000368: Invalid input data?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location, error-000732, error-000368

I'm trying to use `SelectLayerByLocation_managment` in a script and keep getting the following error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
ERROR 000732: Selecting Features: Dataset pnrsLyr does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

I made both feature classes into layers. When I run the same syntax in the Python command window in ArcMap it seems to work fine.

Here's the script:

```
import arcpy

cities = r"C:\RS_Data\Python\Geog485\Lesson3\Lesson3PracticeExercises\Lesson3PracticeExerciseA\Washington.gdb\CityBoundaries"
pnrs = r"C:\RS_Data\Python\Geog485\Lesson3\Lesson3PracticeExercises\Lesson3PracticeExerciseA\Washington.gdb\ParkAndRide"

citiesLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(cities)
pnrsLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pnrs)
print "made feature layers"

nameField = "HasParkAndRide"

selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("citiesLyr","INTERSECT","pnrsLyr")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) tool needs two parameter values, and you are only supplying one.

```
MakeFeatureLayer_management (in_features, out_layer, {where_clause}, {workspace}, {field_info})
```

Try replacing:

```
citiesLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(cities)
pnrsLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pnrs)
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("citiesLyr","INTERSECT","pnrsLyr")
```

with:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(cities,"Cities Layer")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pnrs,"PnR Layer")
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Cities Layer","INTERSECT","PnR Layer")
```